# Octave package installation: "couldn't create installation directory"

Tags: software-installation, package-management, non-root-user, octave

I am trying to install the statistics package (1.0.10) for Octave (3.2.4), which requires the miscellaneous package. When installing the miscellaneous package (1.0.11) I receive the following error:

```
couldn't create installation directory
/usr/lib/octave/packages/3.2/miscellaneous-1.0.11 : Permission denied

error: called from `pkg>copy_files' in file /usr/share/octave/3.2.4/m
/pkg/pkg.m  near line 1473, column 13 error: called from: error:  
/usr/share/octave/3.2.4/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 756, column 5

error:   /usr/share/octave/3.2.4/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 287, column 7
```

I am running Ubuntu 11.04.

What is causing this problem and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you are trying to install the data in a directory where you do not have permission to write data. Either you log in as root or you run the program with root privileges to have access to that directory.

An other way is to specify a `prefix` in octave itself [(see this link)](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Installing-and-Removing-Packages.html), where you want to install your package. Then you would run the following lines in octave:

```
pkg prefix <destination> <destination>
pkg install miscellaneous-1.0.11.tar.gz
```

where `<destination>` is the path to where you want to install your packages.